# What libraries/frameworks/software/services can be used to create mobile (Android/iOS) app to work with ERC20 token?

Tags: erc-20, mobile-wallet

I want to create mobile client that can work with standard functions of ERC20 token (transfer, balanceOf etc.) in specified smart contract.

Ideally mobile client should work with smart contract directly without back-end server.

With libraries/frameworks/software/services can be used to create such mobile application?

Answer (score -1):

You should use [web3.js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/) to construct transactions to interact with whatever tokens you want. Tokens (i.e. smart contracts) are just transactions with addresses you can hit and ask to run certain functions.

You can take a look at [this tutorial on medium](https://medium.com/zeonlab-blockchain-semantic-blog/interaction-with-solidity-using-web3-5a4f1a7166f3) for a look on how to do this, but the gist is that you construct a certain kind of transaction with an address specific to your target smart contract.

Comment: web3.js needs a connection to Ethereum node, the question is how to provide such connection to mobile app

Comment: I see, it is possible to do this with react native and some shimming to get the node modules to work. But I assume you mean natively

Comment: In this context 'node' means Ethereum node, not Node.js

Comment: Indeed. React natives run time is similar to node.js, but some extra customization is necessary for some submodules such as crypto to function properly. For native, you should look at cocoapods and search for web3. A quick search pulled up some non ethereum foundation results with limited functionality based on previous versions. You should investigate to see if that works for you